# Как реализовать перевод сайта в целом на несколько языков

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, перевод

Всем привет, как я вроде бы слышал, что раньше можно было это сделать через google, но теперь эту возможность прикрыли и теперь никак. В ручную как вы понимаете не ахти все это делать, так как будет очень много объектов из базы данных выводиться, так что простая замена через js не подходит. Есть ли у кого-нибудь какая-то новая инфа по поводу этого, буду безмерно благодарен!